# Android: How to connect to a service that is already running when I start my application?

Tags: android, service

I want to connect to my CustomService that extends NotificationListenerService. This NotificationListenerService extends the Service class.

When connecting for the first time, that happens only one time when I activate the "Notification access" on system configurations, it calls the onListenerConnected() method. I can getApplicationContext() and update the UI with the data I have. But I still cannot call the methods from my CustomService class by myself, I have to wait for onNotificationPosted() method to be called by the system then I can update the UI again.

The problem is: when I close the application, I cannot even connect to those methods I said before. The Service is not bound anymore with my application and I cannot find a way to connect to it.

So how to get this service instance, so I can invoke its methods?

I am using this example, tough with some modifications: https://github.com/Chagall/notification-listener-service-example

Comment: Is bound service not works?

Comment: Show some code of both sides(Client and BackGround Service).

Comment: You can check the github example I mentioned. Open the NotificationListenerExampleService class and override onListenerConnected() method. There you can check it only connects the first time as I said.